# Gracefully add padding to left and right edges of certain elements with a smaller browser window

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, margin, padding

I will jump directly into code for easy explanation. I have a simple accordion menu that automatically loads and inserts an image gallery (with caption text) from another html file like so:

```
<section>
    <a class="box-link" href="#.html">Link 1</a>
        <div class="image-gallery">
            <img src="1.jpg"> [...]
            <p>Example loaded paragraph of text</p>
        </div>
    <a class="box-link" href="#.html">Link 2</a>
    <a class="box-link" href="#.html">Link 3</a>
    <a class="box-link" href="#.html">Link 4</a>
</section>
```

And this relevant CSS:

```
section {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 60em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.box-link {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 100%;
}
```

In a large browser window the **section** width maxes out at 60em and is centered on-screen. Every bit of content is flushed to the edges of the column and is lined up nicely.

When the browser window is made smaller than 60em, everything becomes 100% width, and again, is exactly what I want - EXCEPT for the **p** tag. When in this state, I want the **p** tag to have an extra 1em margin or padding on the left and right to keep it from butting up against the edge of the page.

Adding `padding: 0 1em;` to the section tag accomplishes exactly what I want for the **p** tag, but everything else gets the padding as well, which I do not want - In a large browser window, width is still capped at 60em. Once window size is reduced below 60em, the padding is visible.

*So, the question is*: is there a away to achieve extra padding/margin for *only* **p** tags in this "automatic" fashion, or will I have to resort to using a media query to apply something like `p { padding: 0 1em; }` for smaller screens?

Thank you.

Comment: The `p` tag is within your `section` class correct? You should be able to make a style `section > p {padding: 0 1em;} ` (since you said that accomplished what you wanted, but affected all elements. This will only style the paragraph tags within your `section` class.

Comment: This is true, but I do not want the extra padding in a larger browser screen. Thank you though.

Comment: Did you try modifying the box-sizing on the paragraph and/or `.image-gallery` element? (btw, we like demos to go with code.  see http://tinker.io/ or http://jsfiddle.net/; if you need images, try http://placehold.it/ or http://placekitten.com/)

Comment: I just tried it out, but the main problem came from the fact that this "automatically inserted padding" which I was looking for only happens if the padding is applied to the outermost element. Since the `p` tag is nested inside a `section` and `div`, the padding only moves it around in relation to other elements, not directly with the edge of the screen.

Edit: Thanks for the links! I will use these next time. That would be much more clear than writing 2 paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think media query is the only and best option-

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
    p { padding: 0 1em; }
}
```

Comment: Aye, I was afraid of that. Just about all of the rest of the site functions perfectly without the need for a media query, so I was hoping to find another clever solution here.

Comment: And thank you! I did not realize the "enter" key would automatically submit my reply in my last comment.